# Is there method able to block some blocks until some conditions satisfied?

Tags: gpgpu, gpu, cuda

I want to block some blocks until one variable is set to a particular value. So I write this code to test if a simple do-while loop will work.

```
__device__ int tag = 0;
__global__ void kernel() {
    if ( threadIdx.x == 0 ) {
        volatile int v;
        do {
            v = tag;
        }
        while ( v == 0 );
    }
    __syncthreads();
    return ;
}
```

However, it doesn't work(No dead loop occurs, very strange).

I want to ask if any other method is able to block some blocks until some conditions satisfied or if some changes on the code will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently is no reliable  way to perform inter-block synchronization in CUDA.

There are hacky ways to achieve some manner of locking or blocking between blocks with a modest number of total threads, but they exploit undefined behaviour in the execution model which are not guaranteed to run the same way on all hardware or continue to work in the future. The only reliable way to ensure synchronization or blocking between blocks is to us separate kernel launches. If you can't make your algorithm work without interblock synchronization, you either need a new algorithm, or your application is a very poor fit for the GPU architecture.

Comment: Nope. The hacky methods I alluded to use atomics, but they all rely on knowing the order of execution when conditional branches are executed. And they are not universal because they rely on every block in the grid being scheduled and active, which is hardware dependent.

Comment: So can you take a dig on why the code I presented starts failing at 5795+ ? Not sure it is failing due to any of the reasons you mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hackish way I tried to see if it will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

__global__ static
void kernel(int *count, float *data)
{
    count += threadIdx.x;
    data += gridDim.x * threadIdx.x;
    int i = blockIdx.x;
    if (i < gridDim.x - 1) {
        data[i] = i + 1;
        atomicAdd(count, 1);
        return;
    }

    while (atomicMin(count, i) != i);

    float tmp = i + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) tmp += data[j];

    data[i] = tmp;
}

int main(int argc, char **args)
{
        int num = 100;
    if (argc >= 2) num = atoi(args[1]);

    int bytes = num * sizeof(float) * 32;
    float *d_data; cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, bytes);
    float *h_data = (float *)malloc(bytes);
    for (int i = 0; i < 32 * num; i++) h_data[i] = -1; // Being safe                                                                                                                           

    int h_count[32] = {1};
    int *d_count; cudaMalloc((void **)&d_count, 32 * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_count, &h_count, 32 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel<<<num, 32>>>(d_count, d_data);
    cudaMemcpy(&h_count, d_count, 32 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("sum of first %d from thread %d is %d \n", num, i, (int)h_data[num -1]);
        h_data += num;
    }

    cudaFree(d_count);
    cudaFree(d_data);
    free(h_data - num * 32);
}
```

I can not guarantee this will always work. But the breaking point on my card (320M) seems to be for num = 5796. Perhaps a hardware limit of some kind different for each card ?

**EDIT**

The answer to this is that n * (n + 1) / 2 > 2^24 for n > 5795 (which is the single precision limit). The accuracy of integer values beyond this point is undefined. Thanks to talonmies for pointing it out.

```
./a.out 5795
sum of first 5795 from thread 0 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 1 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 2 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 3 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 4 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 5 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 6 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 7 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 8 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 9 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 10 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 11 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 12 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 13 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 14 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 15 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 16 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 17 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 18 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 19 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 20 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 21 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 22 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 23 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 24 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 25 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 26 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 27 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 28 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 29 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 30 is 16793910 
sum of first 5795 from thread 31 is 16793910
```

--

I edited my former code which was using just one block. This is more representative of a real world threads / blocks (the memory accesses are weird and will be slow as hell, but they were done to quickly port my old test code to use multiple threads).

Looks like there are some cases when you can synchronize across blocks, but mostly depends on you knowing certain things before hand (for this particular case, I was only syncing n - 1 blocks before performing an insanely useless count on the last block).

**This is a proof of concept only, do not take the code seriously**

Comment: @Kun, if you do try this remember it is going to be slow as hell. I agree with talonmies on that you need to use a different algorithm or use two kernels. Just did this as an experiment for knowledge sake.

Comment: The 5796 limit you are seeing is a single precision floating point artifact rather than anything to do with the hardware - 16777216 = 2^24 = the limit of the 24 bit mantissa in IEEE 32 bit floating point. I don't see your example as being a valid demonstration of real world synchronization when you are only running 1 thread per block....

Comment: Ah forgot about that! Sleepy head me thinks.